# Error AAR metadat

Tags: java, android, android-studio, aplicación-movil

Como puedo solucionar el error que me sale al lanzar la app en android studio con un móvil se sale error AAR metadata

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Build Gradle**

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar tu build.gradle por favor?

Comment: @Jorgesys agregado. No se por que ahora este problema me da en todos las app que intento ejecutar.

Comment: Tal vez en realidad es problema de la IDE, primero realiza  File > Invalidate caches... y trata nuevamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este tipo de problema:

> 6 Issues were found when checking AAR metadata

**Se presenta cuando alguna de tus dependencias necesita una versión más alta de sistema operativo**, en este caso puedes aumentar el valor de `compileSdk`, por ejemplo si tienes 31 (Android 12), cambia a 32 dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle`.

```
  compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
         ...
         ...
    }
 ...
 ...
```

También puedes mantener tu valor de `compileSdk` pero usar una versión anterior de la dependencia que provoque el conflicto.

Comment: Mi compileSdk es de 32, pero no me deja ejecutar ninguna app

Comment: Realiza File > Invalidate caches... y trata nuevamente.

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: En lugar de 32 le he puesto 33 y se ha solucionado los problemas que me daba pero en uno de los proyectos ahora me salta un error relacionado con que no encuentra la librería de Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar

Comment: Si, como comento en mi respuesta, necesitas una versión más alta de sistema operativo. Ese es otro error relacionado al tema, si quieres realiza otra pregunta, saludos.